# Why use separate servers for front-end and back-end in MERN stack?

Tags: reactjs, mern

In the MERN stack, you often separate the front-end and back-end and start each one independently, as if they were separate servers. Why is this? The front-end server is just a static server, so why not combine it with the main server and just use 1 server? It would give you more control, for example if you wanted server-side traffic analytics.

Comment: Sometimes they _are_ separate servers. Do whichever makes most sense for _your context_.

Comment: Why not put your database server on there too?